# What is the mistake in layout code

Tags: android, layout, user-interface

Whats the mistake in this code, please let me know this way of approach is correct or not.

When i load list items, the list is expanding till the search bar, not the entire screen. please advice  me.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000044">

        <TableRow>
             <EditText 
                 android:id="@+id/txtUserName" 
                 android:width="270dp" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/Search_button"
                 android:width="50dp" /> 
                 />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/Service_name_list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Also tell me, this will work for all screens or not.

Answer (score 0):

Change the second row as below:

```
    <TableRow android:layout_span="2">
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Service_name_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </TableRow>
```

The only thing changed is android:layout_span="2" that is equal to HTML colspan.

Answer (score 0):

Add a layout_span to force the one cell to span two cells.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/Service_name_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_span="2"/>
```